# vuetify v-switch label on two lines

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

For some reason whatever I do the label here refuses to be on one line, here is my code:

```
 <v-container class="px-3">
    <v-layout justify-center>
      <v-flex xs12 sm10>
       <v-layout align-center justify-start>
         <v-flex lg3>
             <v-switch v-model="displayAllUsers"
                        @click.native.stop
                        color="primary"
                        :label="'All users'"
                        @change="toggleAllUsers()"
                        ></v-switch>

            </v-flex>
         </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
 </v-container>
```

Also attached is a pic of what it looks like.
[image: switch image]

Vuetify 1.5.14, using SVG Icons which might be related to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a *lot* of investigating I found out that someone had overridden a vuetify class with a global class like this:

```
.v-input--selection-controls .v-input__control
    margin-left: 89%;
```

Not 100% sure why but this forced the label to be on 2 lines

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine for me here.

Maybe It's because there is something in that container that is causing this issue.

Can you provide more information about what's else is there in that container?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      displayAllUsers: true
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.5.14/vuetify.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
      <v-flex lg3>
        <v-switch 
          v-model="displayAllUsers"             
          @click.native.stop
          color="primary"
          :label="'All users'"                  
          @change="displayAllUsers= false"
         ></v-switch>
      </v-flex>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.0.7/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think you are right but for the life of me I cannot figure out the issue, will add to question additional code.

Comment: @Michael Yes, if it is possible to share additional code it will be helpful to debug.